# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on boot. How can I get back to login screen?

Tags: boot, gnome, 18.04, login-screen, systemd

The Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation (with **4.15.0-24-generic x86_64**) in our living room fails to boot to the login screen. Some other Ubuntu installations in our flat are still working alright (they should be on the same patch level). I used the borked one this morning and it was working okay. Afaik no updates or anything. Normal shutdown around lunch. When I tried to boot it again a couple hours later, it keeps hanging.

After power up, it first hangs a while on the screen with the logo and the dots (no dots move, only the first one is ever shown). After about half a minute or so, it drops to the boot messsages; here is what's shown last:

```
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.erver.tcher Service......tem changes.pp link was shut down....
```

After that, nothing.

I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to a tty login. I can then log in, ping Google, use `apt`, etc. I updated everything and rebooted, but it didn't change anything. Reinstalled *gdm3* and *GNOME*, still nothing.

Any hints?

Comment: I too have this problem ... just started after installing latest updates.

Comment: Me too . Please share if you found an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this link:
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/ubuntu-1804-linux-kernel-update-causes.html

**Kernel image 4.15.0-24 is said to have caused this issue on some systems**.

A patch is said to be available. However, the new **kernel image** package is not yet available in the 'updates' repo. It's still **in 'proposed'**.

What also helped for me is installing **haveged** (user space entropy gathering daemon).

I have two PCs with the same hardware that refused to boot. On the first one, I installed the proposed kernel. On the second one, I just installed haveged. Both solutions solved the boot issue.

See this bug report on Launchpad for reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1779827

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Will try it out tomorrow, and report here.

Comment: I skipped testing the mentioned Kernel, because the suspected reasons for this bug have shifted towards entropy generation. See the recent discussion at the links you provided. Since I only have SSDs installed (no spinning disks) I tried installing `haveged`, which works for me. You might want to update your answer, although until now, there seems to be no clear solution for this.

Comment: @Brutus please, how did you installed haveged? Myself I am stuck in the boot screen.

Comment: @Delosari I used `Ctrl+Alt+F2` to switch to a _tty_. From there I logged in with my username & password and ran `sudo apt install haveged`. Now the boot process is faster. Alternatively, random typing and mouse clicks / movement _seem_ to speed up the boot process too, down to about 4 to 5 minutes from power on to the Gnome login screen.