# 18.04 hangs on boot after system software update (Linux 4.15.0-35)

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, xubuntu, update-manager

after having updated my 18.04 Xubuntu it won't show up the boot up splash window (I have automatic log in activated), my machine gets stuck on exactly the same place as the picture in this post shows:

[18.04 hangs on boot after system software update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052244/18-04-hangs-on-boot-after-system-software-update)

Below those lines in the picture, there's a possibility to enter user name and password in that window which works but it is still in text mode, it also showed a message mentioning something about live patch and something about internet connection not working, don't know if it has something to do with failed update or broken Software Updater (There have been several updates on Software Updater during this autumn, something seems still broken) which hasn't worked properly for a few weeks and which have been complaining about not being able to download packages but after clicking OK yet ,it still shows up a list of updates and one can proceed updating as normal.

Anyhow, I have 2 Xubuntu installs ("dual boot" or what it's called??)
and have been using the latter only for a few months (I am currently writing this post on my first Xubuntu install which uses and older Linux Kernel 4.15.0-24), but my main Xubuntu, the 2nd install, have a Linux 4.15.0-35 kernel and I have tried to boot with previous kernel 4.15.0-34 but with no success.

Alt+F7 doesn't bring up anything, there's only a cursor not reacting, so can only go back to Alt+F1, I am now wondering is there anything I can do to repair my Xubuntu install 2 from the Xubuntu install 1, or do I have to fix the problem from boot up and using command lines and what can one do?

Well, I am a new Linux user and feel quite lost, don't know if it's just 18.04 that is so broken because during the past 5 months in Linux world all the less amusing experiences have been at times rather frustrating, help me stay in Linux land.

---

Just adding some links of similar questions:

[After "security update" to 4.15.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu screen shows log content not login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051555/after-security-update-to-4-15-0-24-generic-26-ubuntu-screen-shows-log-content)

[Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on boot. How can I get back to login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051918/ubuntu-18-04-hangs-on-boot-how-can-i-get-back-to-login-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the failed boot up that never reached the Splash screen but instead remained in a black screen state with a cursor in the upper left corner.
As mentioned earlier, there seem to be some problem with the Software updater, anyhow, after pressing:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or alternatively <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)

which presents the user with a log in request, proceeded by logging in, where after the following message appeared on the screen, in particular the message part at the bottom (as seen in the picture) mentioning something about:

> Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/...

[image: Failed to connect to changelogs.ubuntu.com...]

After some tinkering gave a try to update the Linux distro from the command line using the following 3 commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The following link helped explaining the update procedure from the command line:
[How to install updates via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196768/how-to-install-updates-via-command-line)

The machine appeared to be able to do some kind of update and upgrade, where after the machine was re-booted successfully, this solved at least my problem.